# How can I write this xpath expression in WATIR methods

Tags: watir

I have to form the following xpath via watir methods,

```
//span[@class='fieldTitle-small required z-label'][contains(.,'Address Type')]/../following-sibling::div//input
```

Is there a way to call the watir methods one after another to form this xpath?

Comment: Can you give an HTML sample to test against?

Comment: @JustinKo sure I will update that. But can you tell me I have to locate the element even if the element class miss this 'required' from `fieldTitle-small required z-label`

Comment: So if you have `<span class="fieldTitle-small required z-label">` but only want to locate it on "fieldTitle-small" and "z-label"?

Comment: I would like to locate `<span class="fieldTitle-small z-label"> and <span class="fieldTitle-small required z-label">` with same coding. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That XPath could be done using Watir methods as:

```
browser.span(class: %w(fieldTitle-small required z-label), text: /Address Type/) # //span[@class='fieldTitle-small required z-label'][contains(.,'Address Type')]
       .parent                                                                   # /..
       .following_sibling(tag_name: 'div')                                       # /following-sibling::div                  
       .input                                                                    # //input
```

Note that when using a `:class` locator, an `Array` can be used to specify multiple classes that can appear in any order. The element only has to include those classes, but it can also include any others. For example, `browser.span(class: %w(fieldTitle-small z-label), text: /Address Type/)`, which has the "required" class removed, would match `<span class="fieldTitle-small required z-label">` and `<span class="fieldTitle-small z-label">`.

Comment: Hey, that's exactly what I want and that's why I posted this question. I think this has answered my question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am having a problem here `text: /Address Type/)`, this regular expression find the substring,for an example, If It finds Address Type as substring within a big string, then it would work. But I write contains(.,"Address type") to avoid the space character which comes in, You could see here `//span[@class='fieldTitle-small required z-label'][#{locator.split(/\s+|\u00A0+|Â/).map { |d| "contains(.,'#{d}')" }.join(" and ")}]/../..//input"` the character is u00A0+. So what to do here?

Comment: I think I can't use this watir methods to accomplish this job, because the special character which comes between first and name. I am using my code like contains(.,'First') and contains(.,'Name') which will clearly locate the first name label even if there is a special character.

Comment: You can use wildcards in the RegExp - eg `text: /Address.*Type/` (which is "Address" followed by any number of characters and then "Type"). So something like `text: Regexp.new(locator.split(/\s+|\u00A0+|Â/).join('.*'))` would be equivalent (assuming you at least know the order the words will appear). If the text can have special characters, you might need to escape the words - `Regexp.new(locator.split(/\s+|\u00A0+|Â/).map { |d| Regexp.escape(d) }.join('.*'))`